# Method caching with Spring boot and Hazelcast.How and where do I specify my refresh/reload intervals?

Tags: caching, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache

I realise @Cacheable annotation helps me with caching the result of a particular method call and subsequent calls are returned from the cache if there are no changes to arguments etc.

I have a requirement where I'm trying to minimise the number of calls to a db and hence loading the entire table. However,I would like to reload this data say every day just to ensure that my cache is not out of sync with the underlying data on the database.

How can I specify such reload/refresh intervals.

I'm trying to use Spring boot and hazelcast.All the examples I have seen talk about specifying LRU LFU etc policies on the config file for maps etc but nothing at a method level.
I can't go with the LRU/LFU etc eviction policies as I intend to reload the entire table data every x hrs or x days.

Kindly help or point me to any such implementation or docs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spring `@Cacheable` doesn't support this kind of policies at method level. See for example the code for [CacheableOperation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheableOperation.java).

If you are using hazelcast as your cache provider for spring, you can explicitly evict elements or load datas by using the corresponding IMap from your HazelcastInstance.